# Problem on adding ENV var in Netlify for react app

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, netlify, dotenv, nodeenv

I'm facing a problem on adding env var in netlifiy for react app.But it works perfect on localhost.
Here is the code

```
let appId;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  appId = process.env.REACT_APP_SPEECH_ID;
} else {
  appId = process.env.SPEECH_ID;
}
export default appId;
```

The error I'm facing is

[image]

I'm adding the
Netlify settings also

[image: adding env variable in netlify]

I can't figure out what's happening here. Please help me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is your NODE_ENV set to production?

Comment: @BenGooding Can you say how can I set up NODE_ENV?

Comment: you can set it several ways, on node command line scripts you can add NODE_ENV=production

Comment: most react apps you'll have the dev complier, that will compile on changes like `npm run dev` and the prod way is to do it is `npm run build && npm run start` (but of course this is only an example of how your react might be setup) and that would set the node_env to production https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe Create React App requires your environment variables to be prefixed with `REACT_APP_`, similar to how you've done for `localhost`. I'd keep it the same for production:

```
const appId = process.env.REACT_APP_SPEECH_ID;

export default appId;
```

And then rename the variable in the Netlify admin as `REACT_APP_SPEECH_ID`.